# Cyclic inheritance with Android development - fragments, activities and interfaces

Tags: java, android-fragments, interface, callback, event-listener

I have an app with several fragments and one activity that manages them. In order to avoid coupling between fragments all interactions and changes go through the activity - but here's my problem - I get cyclic inheritance compile time error in the following scenario:

in short:

```
 class A extends Z implements B.listenerB, C.listenerC // cyclic inheritance involving A
 class B extends Y implements A.listenerA  //cyclic inheritance involving B
 class C extends Y implements A.listenerA  // cyclic inheritance involving A
```

in long:

```
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements Activity1.onCustomEventListenerActivity {
           onCustomEventListenerFrag1 listener1;

        public interface onCustomEventListenerFrag1{
         void onCustomEventinFrag1();
        }

        public void someAction(){
           if (successful) 
               listener1.onCustomEvent(); //notify the activity of success
        }

        @Override
        public void onCustomEvent(){
            //respond to change from activity
        }
}
```

Here is my example Activity:

```
public class Activity1 extends FragmentActivity implements Fragment1.onCustomEventListenerFrag1, Fragment2.onCustomEventListenerFrag2{

    //Listens to events in the Activity
    onCustomEventListenerActivity mListener;
    public interface onCustomEventListenerActivity{
       void onCustomEvent();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCustomEventinFrag1(){
        // notify Frag2
        mListener.onCustomEvent();
     }

     @Override
        public void onCustomEventinFrag2(){
        // some code
     }

     public void someAction(){
        if (successful) 
        mListener.onCustomEvent();
     }
}
```

And my other Fragment:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment implements Activity1.onCustomEventListenerActivity {

    //Listens to some event in Frag2
    onCustomEventListenerFrag2 listener2;
    public interface onCustomEventListenerFrag2{
        void onCustomEventinFrag2();
    }

    //Said event
    public void someAction(){
        if (successful)
            listener2.onCustomEventinFrag2(); //notify the activity of success
    }

    //Responding to an event in the activity
    @Override
    public void onCustomEvent(){
        //change something in the fragment
    }
}
```

How can I avoid this error while maintaining loose coupling between fragments? Can I wrap all interfaces in one single class for example and make every class implement needed interface (and if yes, how)? I have seen other examples of cyclic coupling but this one doesn't seem to be the case to my understanding.

Edit: I think I saw why I get the error, but still - is implementing an interface from a certain class the same as inheriting said class?

Thanks!

Comment: Extract the interfaces into their own interface files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, having laid out the question properly actually made me see where my mistake is - B and C depend on A which in turn has some parts that depend on both B and C. A workaround and really - a more optimized solution is to not make the fragments observe the activity but instead just declare some public methods that change the fragments. Then when the activity observes a change in any of its fragments it can respond by searching for the right fragment in which the change should be made and call its public method. This way I avoid creating one too many unnecessary listeners..

So just to make it clearer it would be:

```
class A extends Z implements A.listenerA, B.listenerB{
     @Override
     onEventinA(){
          B fragB = (B)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragBid);
          if (fragB == null){
                fragB = B.newInstance();
          }
          fragB.makeChange();
      }

      onEventinB(){
          A fragA = (A)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragAid);
          if (fragA == null){
                fragA = A.newInstance();
          }
          fragA.makeChange();
      }
 }
```

and Fragments would be pretty much the same as in the question but without implementing any listeners from the activity and with the addition to the public methods.

Answer (score 9):

For me and i think for you as well. notice if you have a interface class that is embedded in a class, so nested. if you do and two classes are using that you'll get this error.  just take the interface and move it into a separate file and do not embed it in the class. that will quiet the error.